# Filter Catalog search results and display it as 2 separate collection in a single page

Tags: catalogsearch

Is it possible to filter the search results by attribute set and display the results as 2 separate collections.Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I tried this

```
<catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
        <label>Quick Search Form</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalogsearch/result" name="search.result" template="catalogsearch/result.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="search_result_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    </block>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                </block>
                <action method="setListOrders"/>
                <action method="setListModes"/>
                <action method="setListCollection"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">

                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="search_result_list_new" template="catalog/product/listnew.phtml">
                    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    </block>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                </block>
                <action method="setListOrders"/>
                <action method="setListModes"/>
                <action method="setListCollection"/>

        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>
```

listnew.phtml

```
$_productCollection = clone $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_productCollection->clear()
                   ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set _id',array('neq'=>1))
                   ->load();
```

I used the above code.i got the search results but the sortby relevance is missing .Is there a better method to achieve this

Comment: Please provide more information. Do you want to display the results for two attribute sets at the same time? Or one result set filtered by attribute set, and one without the filter applied? Should the results be two separate grids/lists, one above the other, or merged in one? Do you only need help with splitting the search result, or also on the rendering side of things?

Comment: Yes i need to display the results for 2 attribute sets one above the other.I have succeded in splitting the results but i am not able to display it correctly.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: You say "but the sortby relevance is missing". Does that mean that your original question has changed to "Why is the sortby relevance option missing from the search results"?

Comment: Sorry for causing the confusion.The method which i tried has few problems such as paginations, sort by option etc.What i want to know is whether it is possible to  to split a collection and show it as two seperate collections in same page.How to approach if its possible.Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Displaying two product collections on one page is certainly possible, though you will have to take care of a few things that the pager works correctly.

First, both toolbar and both pager blocks need to have different names, otherwise both will use the same block instance, rendering the same html.

Then you will need to create your own toolbar class which extends from `catalog/product_list_toolbar` for the second list, and set different values for `$_pageVarName`, `$_orderVarName`, `$_directionVarName`, `$_modeVarName` and `$_limitVarName`.
Alternatively you could hack something with reflection to modify the protected properties, but I advise agains that.
If you use the same toolbar class for both toolbar blocks, they won't know which one should apply a given sorting or ordering. Both will always use the same values, unless they use different HTTP query parameter names.

Thats all, otherwise you should be all good.

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work? I have succeeded in displaying both the product collections. However, the pagination and sort of the second collection keeps on being the same as the first. No luck in overwriting the pager and sort blocks. Anyone has some pointers on how to proceed?

Comment: Can you have any demo code or example so we will get proper idea